# Build application in blackberry native sdk 10.2

Tags: qt, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, momentics

when I running an application from blackberry momentics ide (SDK version 10.2) showing the device version 10.2.0.341 does not support the api level(blackberry native sdk 10.2). I thought it may be for device os version greater than SDK os version. but I did not find Native SDK with 10.2.x version.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand the question.  Also I think I have 10.2.1 of the Momentics IDE, I believe Version 2 is available, but I am finishing a project before I upgrade.  So perhaps these instructions do not apply anyway....

But my level of Momentics includes the ability to build for older OS levels.  To select an older OS level for your build, right mouse click on the project, choose Properties, then "BlackBerry API Level".  Choose the level want to use.

In your case I suspect you have specified 10.1, so you need to change this to 10.2.

If this does not help, can you please explain your problem a little more clearly, perhaps with a screen shot.